Kenmore Elite Double Burner Not Working Together
all.  I have a Kenmore Elite glass top slide-in range.  The double burner doesn't seem to work properly.  When I have the inner burner on, all is good.  When I ask for the larger burner, I only get the outer burner.  But obviously the inner burner works.  So...is my problem the switch?

Perhaps "double burner" means that the user may select either the inner, smaller burner or the larger outer burner...but not both burners at the same time.

What does the manual say?

I'm calling it double burner, but it's a selection of a small burner for a small pan or a larger burner for a larger pan.  To heat a larger pan, you need the inner and outer elements to be on.
